# QML QCamera doesn't show any output window with VideoOutput

Tags: ubuntu, camera, qml, qt5, qtquick2

This is the code which I ran. It showed nothing. There was no QML window at all.

I noticed that when I comment the `VideoOuput` part of code, the window is shown with the red rectangle.

This code runs fine on a laptop, but fails to show even a startup window on the desktop. There is no camera attached with desktop, but I do expect that the program starts and shows the basic window.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Window
{
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: camera.start()

    Rectangle
    {
        color: "red"
        width: 640
        height: 360
        Camera
        {
            id: camera;
        }

        VideoOutput
        {
            source: camera
            anchors.fill: parent
            focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
        }
    }
}
```

Running on **Ubuntu 14.04.3**.

This is a usb camera, and is being detected on my computer.
I can see it working by `xawtv -c /dev/video0`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 with Qt 5.4 from repositories. Works fine. Takes 4-5 seconds to start and then 2 seconds to begin showing video from the camera. I don't know, try gdb to get stacktraces of where it hangs.

Comment: @Velkan See the edit.

Comment: Can't reproduce. desktop without a camera attached starts the application immediately.